# Ralink 5370 interfering with Wireless connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I just bought a *Ralink 5370* (brand new) and when I connect it to **MY COMPUTER** and start navigating (consuming bandwidth), the internet goes south.
Note that it's not the internet's fault; when pinging **192.168.1.1** (Modem *Technicolor TD5130*), it is clear that the problem is the Local Network.

```
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=64   <-- Started scrolling down Facebook
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=546ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1343ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1195ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1495ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2046ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=209ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2127ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2186ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2292ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=729ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3378ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1518ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1327ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=64ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=589ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=959ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=685ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2349ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=84ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=166ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=212ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=93ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
```

I also noticed that this bad connection does not impact just me. My girlfriend has a **notebook** and when my ping with the modem rises, her notebook's ping rises aswell.

Now here it gets tricky: I disabled her notebook's onboard Wireless connection and plugged the Ralink on her Notebook, brought it to the same place where my Desktop is, executed the same steps and the problem does not happen at all. I even plugged my *Microsoft Desktop 3000* kit (Wireless Mouse and Keyboard) in her Notebook to test for interference with the Wireless Transceiver and nothing.

I also copied the driver from her notebook (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\netr28ux.sys) into my computer to use the same driver and the problem persist **ONLY IN MY COMPUTER**.

Also, I tried using a Network Cable and my computer doesn't have a problem with that, only with the Ralink.

Like I mentioned before, when causing this problem, it will affect the whole LAN Network.

Any idea at all on what I can try next?